# Properly get query using Javascript on Django

Tags: javascript, django

I'm developing a website and one of my priorities is a dynamic search table with autocomplete etc.

I found this possible using **ajax** and javascript.

I already implemented  a trigger every time the user types in the search field.

The current problem is getting data from the database, right now I'm getting a 404 error, and no data is being returned.

Code:

views.py

```
def search_bib(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_str=json.loads(request.body).get('searchText')

        bib = Bibrest51.objects.all().filter(
            autor__starts_with=search_str) | Bibrest51.objects.all().filter(
            autor__icontains=search_str)

        data = Bibrest51.objects.all()
        
        return jsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

JS:

```
const searchField = document.querySelector("#searchField");

searchField.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const searchValue = e.target.value;

  if (searchValue.trim().length > 0) {
    console.log("searchValue", searchValue);

    fetch("bibliografia-search", {
      body: JSON.stringify({ searchText: searchValue }),
      method: "POST",
    })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to the site and I hope I didn't do anything wrong with this post. Feedback for improving my post is also appreciated - thank you!

Comment: If you looked up what a 404 error is, you'd see that it indicates that the resource on the server cannot be found.

Comment: Could you show django's urls routes to be sure that routes is not the case of 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I noticed that your function returns data which is all the objects. It should return bib which is the filtered result.

Secondly, It is a problem with your routes as the function is supposed to work as expected